# How do I make a border with an image?

Tags: css

I tried this but for some reason it won't show up.

```css
.bigbox {
    margin: 200px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 1000px;

    display: inline-block;
    border: solid transparent;
    
    background-color:rgba(247, 240, 242, 0.831);
    border-image:       url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/986990253376172032/990279736892747786/Untitled200_20220625193755.png") 30% round;

}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: I can't add it, it says the post is mainly code

Comment: It shows up if you give the border some width. I tried it with 10px. However, you have a possible problem in that that faintly pink circle is repeated around the element OK, but the background-color of the element pokes out at the corners - or is that what you wanted? Perhaps a fuller explanation of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I want to make it look like this basically, I don't know how else to explain. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/986990253376172032/990559741338062858/unknown.png?width=1129&height=701

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Just added border width.

```css
.bigbox {
    margin: 200px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 1000px;

    display: inline-block;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    
    background-color: red;
    border-image:       url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/986990253376172032/990279736892747786/Untitled200_20220625193755.png") 30% round;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox"></div>
```